# Getting key/pair values from HashMap

Tags: java, android

Let us suppose that we add a link from an RSS Feeder into a HashMap as follows.

```
 if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                             //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                            currentMap.put("link", currentChild.getTextContent());


                            }
```

In other words our HashMap containts a key/value pairs as shown...

```
   ("link",http://........),
   ("link",http://........),
   ("link",http://........) and so on....
```

Now I want to extract those links in the following method..

```
   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
```

I want to open the links in WebViews. I did something similar,but was saving data like titles and links into a simple ArrayList..Now I am trying something similar with HashMaps,and I am stuck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: map.put("key", "value"); map.put("key", "value"); results in the map only containing 1 value. you should consider using an array(list) for things like this. to loop over map and get key/value you can use for(Map.Entry<Key, Value> cur: map.entrySet()) { cur.getKey(); cur.getValue(); } for example.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Hello friends..I haven't tried anything yet..I ll get back you,when I have something better to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found time to fix it.

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;
  .
  .
  .
    @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    HashMap<String, String> hm = results.get(position);
                    String link = hm.get("link");
                    L.m(link);
                    if (!link.equals("")) {
                        //do what ever you like to do with link;
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
                        browserIntent.putExtra("url",link);
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                }
```

I didn't use any foreach loop as the key/values pairs where repeating inside the onItemClick() method(get(position). Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Theo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any implementation of MultiMap concept. For example apache commons-collection or guava or other implementation:

some explanation of MultiMap with guava:

http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

some explanation of MultiMap with apache commons-collection library:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

At last you can implement MultiMap by yourself as explained in first link. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need a collection with a well-defined order to make this work since ListView assumes an ordinal position for each of its items.

Try something like the following:

Create your collection of links using a List containing android.util.Pair like this:

```
private List<Pair<String, Uri>> links = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Uri>>();
```

Create an

```
ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, Uri>>
```

and initialize it with the aforementioned list

Then your onItemClick implementation will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, Uri>> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, Uri>>)parent.getAdapter();
    Pair<String, Uri> item = adapter.getItem(position);

    String linkLabel = item.first;
    Uri linkUri = item.second;
}
```

Finally, to avoid duplicates in your list, you can make use of the contains method:

```
    Pair<String, Uri> linkToAdd = new Pair("Amazon", Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com"));

    if (!links.contains(linkToAdd))
    {
        links.add(linkToAdd);
    }
```